# how to use form control class in bootstrap templates?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I use a bootstrap Template. I use bootstrap modal for register in my website.
for textboxes, I use form-control class but it does not work.
Can anyone help me?

```
  ...<div class="modal-body" dir="rtl" style="font-family:BYekan; text-align:center">

    <center>    
        <div class="form-group">
<asp:TextBox ID="txtemail_reg" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder=" Email Address" Width="300px"></asp:TextBox>
            </div> ....
```

Comment: please provide your code OR fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the css of template. the input tag has some css,I remove those and my problem fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you placed class="form-group". For example

---

```
<form class="form-inline">

    <div class="form-group">

      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Amount">

    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Transfer cash</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I Edit my question. I think it is because of the Template that I use it